# How to make Ctrl+C operation indicate that it did something, in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface

Is it possible to enable in Windows some visual effect when copying into the copy/paste buffer occurs? Normally, Windows does not indicate in any way that the copy/paste buffer has just been updated (like as the result of Ctrl-C).

The reason why I'm asking:
Ctrl+C often does nothing. Hard to say why (maybe focus was not set precisely or whatever). But there is no visual indication if anything has actually happened or not. So I often end up with the situation that I pressed Ctrl-C in one window, switched to another, clicked Ctrl-V and found out that older value of the buffer was inserted. So, I have to start everything over.

It would be much easier for me to see that Ctrl+C did something in the first place. If nothing happened (no buffer copy operation occurred), I'd immediately set the focus on the element (or anything like that) without wasting time on deleting wrong copy result and returning back from the destination to the source window.

Is it possible to enable some sort of a visual indication of "buffer has been updated" operation? Like some kind of a registry setting?

Comment: This probably would be solved with some kind of script or with [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) but I have little knowledge with that.

Comment: You are using this shortcut in which application?  WSL doesn’t support the copy and paste in 1803 or below

Comment: Reasons Copy may not "do" anything: Your keystrokes didn't register, the application does not support copy (VMs, RDP), there was nothing selected. For the first and second, nothing would have happened because the instruction never reached the target, so nothing would trigger a check and an indicator. Therefore, any such system would have to be a constant indicator, simply updating on a change in the buffer and indicating that such a change had occurred, rather than a trigger-based indicator.

Comment: I don't understand. If nothing happened (keystrokes didn't register), nothing should occur (nothing needs to be triggered and so on). But if it DID occur (copy succeeded), I want a visual indication. This way I will distinguish between "nothing happened" and "copy succeeded".

Comment: Not as simple as you wish but Clipboard history can be accesses by "Windows Key-V" You have to enable but it will show the recent items added to clipboard.

Comment: A registry setting assumes Microsoft has already built something like this in and it just needs the right switch to "activate" the effect, but Microsoft HASN'T integrated anything like this. This will require a significant system plugged deep into protected parts of the OS.